# Не запускается Apache 2.4 с Open Server после перезагрузки

Tags: openserver

Начал изучать PHP, но возникли ряд проблем.
Запускаю Open Server x64 с разрешения Администратора. Запустился красный флажок, через него запускаю Open Server, флажок меняется на жёлтый и потом опять на красный.
Лог:

```
2021-06-07 22:09:47  --------------------------------------------
2021-06-07 22:09:47  Начало процедуры запуска сервера
2021-06-07 22:09:48  Обновление Hosts файла
2021-06-07 22:09:48  Обновление конфигурации MySQL-5.6
2021-06-07 22:09:48  Обновление конфигурации Sendmail
2021-06-07 22:09:48  Обновление конфигурации PHP-5.5
2021-06-07 22:09:48  Обновление конфигурации PHPMyAdmin
2021-06-07 22:09:48  Обновление конфигурации Apache-2.4
2021-06-07 22:09:48  Запуск MySQL-5.6
2021-06-07 22:09:48  Запуск Apache-2.4
2021-06-07 22:09:48  Проверка состояния сервера
2021-06-07 22:10:34  Не удалось запустить Apache-2.4
2021-06-07 22:10:34  Сбой запуска!
2021-06-07 22:10:34  --------------------------------------------
2021-06-07 22:10:34  Начало процедуры остановки сервера
2021-06-07 22:10:34  Остановка системных модулей
2021-06-07 22:10:36  Отключение виртуального диска
2021-06-07 22:10:36  Сервер успешно остановлен за 1,813 секунд!
```

Вчера запустил, всё работало. Сегодня не запускается.

Comment: Запустил в режиме откладки, указывает:

d:\ospanel\modules\http\Apache-2.4>"d:\ospanel\modules\http\Apache-2.4\bin\httpd.exe" -f "d:\ospanel\modules\http\Apache-2.4\conf\httpd.conf"
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 132 of D:/OSPanel/modules/http/Apache-2.4/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: \xce\xef\xe5\xf0\xe0\xf6\xe8\xee\xed\xed\xe0\xff \xf1\xe8\xf1\xf2\xe5\xec\xe0 \xed\xe5 \xec\xee\xe6\xe5\xf2 \xe7\xe0\xef\xf3\xf1\xf2\xe8\xf2\xfc %1.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена.
Необходимо было сделать установку библиотек MSVC++
Можно закрыть.